# displaying only one entry with useQuery

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to just display one value from a query and I'm wondering why the first snippet of code does not display the name while the other one does

this one does not work:

```
const EXCHANGE_RATES = gql`
  query {
    profiles (limit: 1){
        id
        name
  }
}
`;

export const ExchangeRates: React.FC<ExchangeRatesProps> = () => {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(EXCHANGE_RATES);

    if (loading) return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
    if (error) return <Text>Error :(</Text>;
    
    return  (
        <View >
            <Text>
                {data.profiles.name}
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

but this one does:

```
export const EXCHANGE_RATES = gql`
  query {
    profiles (limit: 1){
        id
        name
  }
}
`;

export const ExchangeRates: React.FC<ExchangeRatesProps> = () => {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(EXCHANGE_RATES);

    if (loading) return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
    if (error) return <Text>Error :(</Text>;


    return data.profiles.map(({ id, name} : {id:number, name:string}) => (
        <View >
            <Text>
                {id} : {name}
            </Text>
        </View>
    ));
}
```

Comment: Is the data returned from useQuery an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data.profiles` is an array. You have to do something like `data.profiles[0].name`. If you do `console.log(data.profiles)` you'll see it is an array